# Octobercms - Extra column with buttons (edit, ...)

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I want to make a list from "sports" with on every row an edit button (or manage). How can I do this?

There is a method to override data (if it's null for example -> [Empty]).
But how can I add a button with a link to the managepage for that particular sport?

An option: using the toolbarpartial but I want it as a button on every row...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is too vague. Kindly add respective code.

Comment: Is it on front-end or backend?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this

frist create a partial in your controller views folder

```
<button data-request="yourHandler" ... data-request-data="rowid: <?php echo $record->id ?>">edit</button>
```

then in the list config use this

```
edit_button:
    label: Edit
    type: partial
    cssClass: nolink  
    path: $/foo/bar/controllers/.../_editbutton_column.htm
```

then add handler method and view to your controller for edit page

Comment: The "cssClass: nolink" part was exactly what I was looking for, tank you!